# lazyload picture (webp + fallback)

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, webp, jquery-lazyload, image-optimization

I would like to lazyload webp-images with a fallback-image.

My html looks currently like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>
<img class="center lazy" data-original="./bilder/uebersetzung-marketing-bwl.png" width="593" style="max-width: 100%" alt="Übersetzung für Marketing und Wirtschaft">
```

And if I make it like this, its not showing the webp image in chrome:

```
 <picture>
   <source class="center lazy" srcset="./bilder/uebersetzung-marketing-bwl.webp" type="image/webp">
   <img class="center lazy" data-original="./bilder/uebersetzung-marketing-bwl.png" width="593" style="max-width: 100%" alt="Übersetzung für Marketing und Wirtschaft">
 </picture>
```

Do I have to use another library to solve it or what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is in wordpress, you can use this plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express/)

it will load webp for webp supported browser, otherwise it will fallback to the main file.